# scipy curve_fit returns initial estimates

Tags: python, scipy, curve-fitting

To fit a hyperbolic function I am trying to use the following code:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

def hyperbola(x, s_1, s_2, o_x, o_y, c):
    # x > Input x values
    # s_1 > slope of line 1
    # s_2 > slope of line 2
    # o_x > x offset of crossing of asymptotes
    # o_y > y offset of crossing of asymptotes
    # c   > curvature of hyperbola

    b_2 = (s_1 + s_2) / 2
    b_1 = (s_2 - s_1) / 2

    return o_y + b_1 * (x - o_x) + b_2 * np.sqrt((x - o_x) ** 2 + c ** 2 / 4)

min_fit = np.array([-3.0, 0.0, -2.0, -10.0, 0.0])
max_fit = np.array([0.0, 3.0, 3.0, 0.0, 10.0])
guess = np.array([-2.5/3.0, 4/3.0, 1.0, -4.0, 0.5])

vars, covariance = curve_fit(f=hyperbola, xdata=n_step, ydata=n_mean, p0=guess, bounds=(min_fit, max_fit))
```

Where n_step and n_mean are measurement values generated earlier on. The code runs fine and gives no error message, but it only returns the initial guess with a very small change. Also, the covariance matrix contains only zeros. I tried to do the same fit with a better initial guess, but that does not have any influence. 
Further, I plotted the exact same function with the initial guess as input and that gives me indeed a function which is close to the real values. Does anyone know where I make a mistake here? Or do I use the wrong function to make my fit?

Comment: Independently of whatever is going on here, note that `vars` is the name of a Python built-in so you may want to avoid using that as a variable name as it ends up shadowing the built-in.

Comment: But actually, if your given `guess` happens to provide (near-)optimal results with whatever `n_step` and `n_mean` is, then what is the issue exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue must lie with `n_step` and `n_mean` (which are not given in the question as currently stated); when trying to reproduce the issue with some arbitrarily chosen set of input parameters, the optimization works as expected. Let's try it out.

First, let's define some arbitrarily chosen input parameters in the given parameter space by

```
params = [-0.1, 2.95, -1, -5, 5]
```

Let's see what that looks like:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
xs = np.linspace(-30, 30, 100)
plt.plot(xs, hyperbola(xs, *params))
```

[image]

Based on this, let us define some rather crude inputs for `xdata` and `ydata` by

```
xdata = np.linspace(-30, 30, 10)
ydata = hyperbola(xs, *params)
```

With these, let us run the optimization and see if we match our given parameters:

```
vars, covariance = curve_fit(f=hyperbola, xdata=xdata, ydata=ydata, p0=guess, bounds=(min_fit, max_fit))
print(vars)  # [-0.1   2.95 -1.   -5.    5.  ]
```

That is, the fit is perfect even though our `params` are rather different from our `guess`. In other words, if we are free to choose `n_step` and `n_mean`, then the method works as expected.

In order to try to challenge the optimization slightly, we could also try to add a bit of noise:

```
np.random.seed(42)
xdata = np.linspace(-30, 30, 10)
ydata = hyperbola(xdata, *params) + np.random.normal(0, 10, size=len(xdata))
vars, covariance = curve_fit(f=hyperbola, xdata=xdata, ydata=ydata, p0=guess, bounds=(min_fit, max_fit))
print(vars)  #  [ -1.18173287e-01   2.84522636e+00  -1.57023215e+00  -6.90851334e-12   6.14480856e-08]
plt.plot(xdata, ydata, '.')
plt.plot(xs, hyperbola(xs, *vars))
```

[image]

Here we note that the optimum ends up being different from both our provided `params` and the `guess`, still within the bounds provided by `min_fit` and `max_fit`, and still provided a good fit.

Comment: Thanks! It was indeed related to the input values. Just tried to run the same code again, but converted the input data from float32 to float64, which solved the problem. Still strange that the function does not give a warning or converts the data itself...

Comment: Good catch, and highly curious! Since SciPy uses MINPACK for its implementation of LM (which isn't actually the algorithm used here), the data type might end up mattering there, but certainly this behavior is unexpected.

Comment: Okay, it's not the MINPACK interface that is to blame here; the issue is that the initial step size is square root of the epsilon of `np.float64`, which causes the dfs to vanish in the `np.float32` case.